# How to display highest scorer and lowest scorer with their name, average and also grade

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently doing an assignment to input student name, English mark, math mark, and science mark. I have use the listbox as the code below. Then I also need to display the highest scorer and lowest scorer. I have tried and I have no idea how can I do it. Can somebody help me out?

And another thing is, how can I align the listbox items?

```
Public Class StudentsGradeForm
    Dim StdDetails As String = "{0, -10}{1, -20}{2, -20}{3, -20}{4, -20}{5, -20}"
    Dim num1integer, num2integer, num3integer As Integer
    Dim resultdouble As Double
    Dim grade As String

    Private Sub exitbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles exitbtn.Click
        Dim iExit As DialogResult

        iExit = MessageBox.Show("Confirm you want to exit the system", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

        If iExit = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Calcbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Calcbtn.Click
        num1integer = num1txt.Text
        num2integer = num2txt.Text
        num3integer = num3txt.Text

        resultdouble = (num1integer + num2integer + num3integer) / 3

        outlbl.Text = resultdouble

        If resultdouble >= 80 And resultdouble <= 100 Then
            grade = "A"

        ElseIf resultdouble >= 70 And resultdouble <= 79 Then
            grade = "B"

        ElseIf resultdouble >= 60 And resultdouble <= 69 Then
            grade = "C"

        ElseIf resultdouble >= 50 And resultdouble <= 59 Then
            grade = "D"

        ElseIf resultdouble >= 40 And resultdouble <= 49 Then
            grade = "E"
        Else
            grade = "F"
        End If

        outgradelbl.Text = grade
    End Sub

    Private Sub StudentsGradeForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format(StdDetails, "Name", "Eng", "Math", "Sci", "Average", "Grade"))
    End Sub

    Private Sub updatebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles updatebtn.Click
        Dim StudentName, EnglishMark, MathMark, ScienceMark As String
        Dim Average As Double
        Dim Grade As Char

        StudentName = nametxt.Text
        EnglishMark = num1txt.Text
        MathMark = num2txt.Text
        ScienceMark = num3txt.Text
        Average = outlbl.Text
        Grade = outgradelbl.Text

        ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format(StdDetails, StudentName, EnglishMark, MathMark, ScienceMark, Average, Grade))
    End Sub

    Private Sub clrbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles clrbtn.Click
        nametxt.Clear()
        num1txt.Clear()
        num2txt.Clear()
        num3txt.Clear()
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you learnt about classes and properties yet? That would be a better way to store the data than a string.

Comment: No I haven't learn about classes and properties.

Comment: OK, have you learnt about arrays, and about converting (parsing) strings to numbers?

Comment: Yes I have learnt array but parsing not yet

Comment: I don't want to subvert the order in which you teacher has organised your course, and today I can't find an introduction to classes in VB.NET that I like, but if you are really keen to learn then I recommend the [video tutorials on VB.NET by Bob Tabor](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD5Oo36NFSb6_u5aqqF_Aztx8OcoZb5S8). If I show you how to do the task with *parallel arrays*, you may well find that your next lesson is about how parallel arrays are not so good and classes are much better.

Comment: *how can I align the listbox items?* - use a monospaced font, such as Consolas or Courier New.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class student:

```
Public Class Student
  Dim _Name as String
  Dim _Eng as Integer
  etc...
```

Then you write your properties in your class:

```
Property Name as String
  Get
     Return _Name
  End Get
  Set(value As String)
     _Name = value
  End Set
End Property
```

And you do the same for the other five fields you have.
Then you'll have to convert/parse your string into a numeric value (I assume you will use Integer). So you can do either:

```
CInt(myString)
Integer.TryParse(myString)
```

And when you want to convert back to string you just do:

```
myInteger.ToString()
```

And if you want to store values into your student Object:

```
Dim myStudent As New Student
myStudent.Name = Field1txt.Text 'the string that should represent the student name
```

Long story short, it's easier and faster, if you need to do some math, to store your values as Integer instead of String. If you have a mix of the two and you want to keep them together in one entity, just create a custom Class.

Comment: It would be tidier to use [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties) as nothing special needs to be done in the getter/setter.

Comment: Class level variables are normally declared with Private instead of Dim.

Comment: yeah right i forgot

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Option Strict. Project Properties -> Compile tab. Also for future projects Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults This should **ALWAYS** be on. (actually there are rare occasions where it needs to be off)

```
Public Class StudentGrade
    Public Property StudentName As String
    Public Property EnglishMark As Integer
    Public Property MathMark As Integer
    Public Property ScienceMark As Integer
    Public Property Average As Double
    Public Property Grade As String

    Public Sub New(Name As String, EngMark As Integer, MthMark As Integer, SciMark As Integer)
        StudentName = Name
        EnglishMark = EngMark
        MathMark = MthMark
        ScienceMark = SciMark
        CalculateAverage()
        CalculateGrade()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CalculateAverage()
        Dim resultdouble = (EnglishMark + MathMark + ScienceMark) / 3
        Average = resultdouble
    End Sub

    Private Sub CalculateGrade()
        Select Case Average
            Case >= 80
                Grade = "A"
            Case >= 70
                Grade = "B"
            Case >= 60
                Grade = "C"
            Case >= 50
                Grade = "D"
            Case >= 40
                Grade = "E"
            Case Else
                Grade = "F"
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

First, let's consider the class. Classes can have Properties and Methods among other things. The classes data (like `Name` or `MathMark`) is contained in the properties. The methods act on this data. The class is the cookie cutter and an instance of the class is the cookie. To create an instance of `StudentGrade`, call `Sub New`. This `Sub New` has parameters that are used to set the values of several properties. It also calls `Private` methods (visible only in the class) that set the other properties. Now we have a fully fleshed out instance of the `StudentGrade` class.

The Average can have values between 79 - 80, 69 - 70, 59 - 60, and 49 - 50. Your code would have missed these values and failed the student I changed the code to a Select Case for readability.

Back to the Form class. We have a form level variable StuList to hold the instances of the StudentGrade class that we create.

```
Private StuList As New List(Of StudentGrade)
```

The Form load sets the `DataSource` property of a `DataGridView`. This should be much easier than trying to make a ListBox line up. You fill in the text boxes with appropriate data and click Button1 to create a new student.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.DataSource = StuList
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CreateNewStudent()
End Sub
```

In the `CreateNewStudent` method we first validate the user input. The `TryParse` method checks the first parameter to see if it can be converted to the indicated type. It returns `True` or `False`. If it returns `True` it fills in the second parameter with the converted value. If it returns False we don't want to continue with the method so we inform the user and exit the sub.

We call the `New` method with `Dim stu As New StudentGrade` and pass the required parameters to fill the properties of this instance. Add this instance of the class to the list. You can use the properties of `StudentGrade` to display in your Labels.

Finally we remove the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView` and reset it to the list with the new addition. This is sort of cludgy way to do this but it works without introducing more complicated approaches.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim max = StuList.Max(Function(stu) stu.Average)
    MessageBox.Show($"The highest average is {max:N0}")
    Dim min = StuList.Min(Function(stu) stu.Average)
    MessageBox.Show($"The lowest average is {min:N0}")
End Sub
```

After you have created the students you want to display the minimum and maximum average. You can use an extension method of the List(Of T) class.